# Converting defined Jframe size to auto-sizing based on screensize

Tags: java, swing, resize, awt

I am working on a java project, a binary clock along with weather stats from an API. When originally writing it I made the mistake of defining the frame size as the specific resolution of my screen. Now that I have gotten a new laptop with a different screen size I have recognized my mistake and I am unsure of how to fix it. (its all cut off since my old laptop was 4k and my new laptop is not).

All of the components are also a defined size based on the defined size of my Panel and frame size which are both
`.setSize(2000,1500);` I have tried to insert

```
           Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
           frame.setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
```

in my frame:

```
               JFrame frame = new JFrame("12-Hour Binary Clock");
               frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
               frame.setSize(2000,1500);
               frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY.darker().darker().darker());
               frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

as well as modifying my main panel, `Panel` where all the components are inside of:

```
       JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
       Panel.setLayout(null);
       Panel.setSize(2000, 1500);
       Panel.setBackground(null);
       Panel.setLocation(400, 100);
       Panel.setVisible(true);
```

to

```
       JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
       Panel.setLayout(null);
       Panel.setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
       Panel.setBackground(null);
       Panel.setLocation(400, 100);
       Panel.setVisible(true);
```

Adding everything to `Panel` and `Panel` to `frame`:

```
   //adding components to panel and panel to frame at end of program
   Panel.add(inner);
   Panel.add(labelOne); //JLabel components inside Panel
   Panel.add(labelTwo);
   Panel.add(labelFour);
   Panel.add(labelEight);
   frame.add(weather);
   frame.add(Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

but it did not seem to do anything.
I don't think I have a good grasp of how to do this. Any tips are appreciated considering I definitely am not doing this right.

I'm not sure if I just need to adjust the size of `Panel` and `frame` since that is where everything is inside of but since it did not do anything it seems I will have to do more. Will I need to adjust the size of all components?

Also not sure why I made `Panel` the same size as `frame` instead of just adding everything to `frame`. I'm revisiting this code after a long time.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) ..

Comment: .. along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 4) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 5) `Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); frame.setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);` Use instead `JFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)` (check with compiler / docs / common sense)

Answer (score 1):

Since your layout is `null` the components will most likely not resize themselves when the window changes size. You will either have to manually move and resize the components to fit the window or add a layout.

I suggest using either a BorderLayout, a GridLayout or a combination of the two, depending on how advanced your GUI is. A good way to learn the layouts is to use Oracles tutorials:

BorderLayout:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

GridLayout:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html